# Designing an back-end and front-end architecture for biomedical application

Tags: node.js, architecture, google-cloud-platform, backend, bioinformatics

I have a biomedical application where I am continuously monitoring a patient'a ECG data. In real time, I am logging all **raw** values and processed values **(heartrate, BP etc.)**. Since the patient is wearing the sensor 24x7, s/he is going to send a lot of these data every second.

Let say I am logging JSON values with timestamps like this in my application -

```
data = {
   "raw":"293.110", // these are generated every mill second
   "heartrate":"79", // every 1 second
   "bpH":"123", // every 5 minutes
   "bpL":"80", // every 5 mins
   "artifacts":"1" // if body moves 1, otherwise 0
   "time":"14:16:51 GMT+0530" 
}
```

Then how should I architect my application in such a way that it should take care of scale-ability  in term of supporting thousands of user logging huge amount of data every mill second.

Now, What I am going to do with these data -

- Plot/Visualize data in real time, obviously, for health tracking for patient and doctor.
- Store data in database for future use
- Retrieve data from database -

  - To plot historical vitals
  - To plot raw data for analysis
  - To apply ML for generating further insights.

What I am planning to use for

- **Frontend** : NodeJS + electronJS + Web Technologies
- **Backend** : Google Cloud Platform

Where I need help

- As you can understand from above, it is going to send a lot of data to backend hence how should I design my backedn with GCP
- How to choose correct offering from GCP
- If GCP is overkill for my application, then what would be other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to start by reviewing some solutions/reference architectures other people have used:

- [Patient Monitoring Reference Architecture](http://gcp.solutions/diagram/Patient%20Monitoring)
- [Sensor stream ingest and processing reference architecture](http://gcp.solutions/diagram/Sensor%20stream%20ingest%20and%20processing)
- [stream analytics solution](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/big-data/overview/stream-analytics/)

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. Let me look into it. :) :)